# Able to have pgfgantt move bars based on dependancies

Tags: pgfgantt

Gantt Bars seem to be defined with a start and end time period:

```
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2}
```

Since all my tasks take a fixed time and are dependant on each other, is it possible to have all the trailing gantt bars pushed back if the earlier dependancies go longer?  In other words, a ganttbar simply has a length, and if it is dependant on another bar, it simply starts when the last one end.  Otherwise, I have to manually update all the beginning and end dates.  Any solutions out there?

Comment: Could you expand this into a full minimal example?  Possibly with an example use and expected output?

Comment: @close voters: What (other than the lack of an MWE) makes this question unclear? I voted for reopen; I thought it was an interesting request and was looking into a solution.

Comment: Only way i found to do that was to make the calculations within a spreadsheet with latex code in cells to copy paste in document after.